# How to replace a entire line from a file which has a content /u02/app/oracle-1/product/12.2.0/db_1:N to /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:Y

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Can we do it using sed and if so how?

How to replace a entire line from a file which has a content /u02/app/oracle-1/product/12.2.0/db_1:N to /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:Y using Sed

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy with `sed` command. Use below `sed` command which will do it for you.

```
sed 's|'/u02/app/oracle-1/product/12.2.0/db_1:N'|'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:Y'|g' your_original_file > newfile

mv newfile your_original_file
```

In above example, first `sed` command will replace `/u02/app/oracle-1/product/12.2.0/db_1:N` with `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:Y` and modified text will be redirect to newfile. In the new file you can review the changes whether correct or not.

With `mv` command you can rename newfile to your_original_file. So above example is safe. But you can do so with a single command like below, but you should be careful here, because if anything wrong you will be in trouble :-)

```
sed -i.bak 's|'/u02/app/oracle-1/product/12.2.0/db_1:N'|'/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:Y'|g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trials got it done.

sudo sed -i.bak '/^G:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/db_1:/ s/N/Y/'